# dynamic paint in render mode breaks geometry

Tags: rendering

[image]

In Solid Mode the Dynamic paint works properly and the footprints are clearly visible. But in render mode the geometry gets collapsed . I have used displacement and noise textures fir the sand material .. Is this because of that or do i have to add more geometery to the sand[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is the displacement, as that actually changes geometry, and is not visible in solid viewport, only in cycles.

I guess displacement occurs after the dynamic paint, which leads to the displacement destroying the footprint shape.

Try changig the order of the modifier stack, having the dynamik paint after the displacement.

If that is not possible, try to apply the displacement before using the dynamic paint.

***If you are using the displacement not in a modifier but in a displacement node:***
The shader nodes *always* gets evaluated *after* the modifier stack.
But as long as the dispplcement occurs after the dynamik paint, it wll destroy your geometry. So you cannot make a node setup work with your desired dynamic paint effect. You need to change the evaluation order so that displacement occurs first, which means you have to move your displcement from the shader nodes to the displacement modfier, where you can put it before the dynamic paint.

Comment: For further suggestions i would need to  have the according .blend file

Comment: Sure But the thing is I did not use the displacement "modifier" to this , instead i applied displacement node

Comment: so ovviously the displacement shader node seems to get evaluated after the dynamik paint (which i would have expected the other way round). I think you have to rearrange your sccene in a way to make sure the dynamik paint is evaluated after the displacement, maybe by applying or baking the displcement into your scene before doing the dynamik painting.

Comment: @maddes8cht The shader nodes are always evaluated last before render, so all modifiers etc. are evaluated before them. For example it makes no sense to have texture coordinates, normals, bump nodes etc. be evaluated before the actual geometry they should be working on.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ah, you are right. So yes, he has to change the setup so that displacement occurs first, before the dynamik paint. It will never work when displcement occurs after dynamik paint. To do that he might move the displacement into a modifier

Comment: Guys Thank you so much it worked .. Means a lot

Comment: Glad that it helped :)
Now, if the Answer was of value, then have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers